# Node.js detailed documentation?

Tags: node.js

How come the documentation for things like http.IncomingMessage doesn't have all the attributes and methods?

I've seen tutorials use

```
http.createServer(function(request, response){
    request.url
```

but how does one know such attribute 'url' even exist?

The docs at http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_incomingmessage only gives a description of it.

Comment: That link says it's an object created by either a server or client request, and below it, it talks about `message.url`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, let's start with the `http.createServer` docs.
http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_requestlistener

> `http.createServer([requestListener])`
>
> Returns a new web server object.The requestListener is a function which is automatically added to the 'request' event.

So then we look up the request event.
http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_request

> Event: 'request'
>   `function (request, response) { }`
>
> Emitted each time there is a request. Note that there may be multiple requests per connection (in the case of keep-alive connections). request is an instance of http.IncomingMessage and response is an instance of http.ServerResponse.

So now we know the call callback accepts `request` and `response` as arguments, and that `request` is an instance of `IncomingMessage`.  So then we lookup `IncomingMessage`.
http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_incomingmessage

> `http.IncomingMessage`
>
> An IncomingMessage object is created by http.Server or http.ClientRequest and passed as the first argument to the 'request' and 'response' event respectively. It may be used to access response status, headers and data.
>
> It implements the Readable Stream interface, ***as well as the following additional events, methods, and properties.***

So we scroll down a bit until we get to this:
http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_url

> `message.url`
>
> Only valid for request obtained from http.Server.
>
> Request URL string. This contains only the URL that is present in the actual HTTP request.

Seems pretty straight forward.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I was confused because I skimmed the IncomingMessage section. The bottom parts felt like completely different objects that were unrelated.